# XQUERY select different rows in multiple tags

Tags: oracle, xquery, xmltype, xmltable

I have a table in oracle

```
create table MOVIE
(MOVIE_ID VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
TITLE VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
DIRECTOR VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
WRITER VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
GENRE VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
RELEASE_DATE DATE,
RUNTIME NUMBER,
REVIEWS XMLTYPE);
```

REVIEW IS OF XML TYPE

Each Reviews has multiple tags of `REVIEW(MORE THAN ONE TAG WITH A TAG)`
I Have 25 such Reviews with multiple Review Tag inside each of them

I want the ids of repeating tag in different rows

I have written the following query

```
SELECT 
XMLQuery(
'for $i in distinct-values (/Reviews/REVIEW/ID)
return data($i)'
PASSING REVIEWS RETURNING CONTENT) ID
FROM MOVIE;
```

The above query is giving me the output as 
M17 M18 M19  if there are inside the same REVIEW tag.

I am getting all the three in a single row
I want them in 3 different rows.

```
M17
M18
M19
```

Any idea whats wrong with the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLTable() join with `MOVIE` table must work for **11g** :

```
select 
   m.movie_id,
   id_list.review_id
from 
  movie m,
  XMLTable(
    'for $i in distinct-values($param/Reviews/REVIEW/ID) return $i'
    passing m.reviews as "param"
    columns review_id varchar2(4000) path '//ID'
  ) id_list
```

But in case of **10g** it goes harder, because such construction always get value for `REVIEWS` field from first selected record.
Tricks with multisets won't work and produce same results (got values from first record).

I found only solution for **10g** by aggregating all results by XMLAgg() into one record and then build new dataset from that record with XMLTable().

```
select
  movie_id,
  review_id
from 
  XMLTable(
    '
      for $movie in $big_root/full_list/movie_entry,
          $review_id in $movie/ID
      return <row><movie_id>{data($movie/@movie_id)}</movie_id><review_id>{$id}</review_id></row> 
    '
    passing 
      (
        select 
          XMLElement("full_list", 
            XMLAgg(
              XMLElement("movie_entry",
                XMLAttributes(m.movie_id as "movie_id"),
                XMLQuery(
                  'for $i in distinct-values($param/Reviews/REVIEW/ID) return $i'
                   passing by value m.reviews as "param"
                   returning content
                ) 
              )
            )
          )
        from 
          movie m
      )
    as "big_root"
    columns 
      movie_id varchar2(4000) path '//row/movie_id',
      review_id varchar2(4000) path '//row/review_id'
  )
```

Sorry, I can't test now this query but hope it's enough to give you idea about what it looks like.

*P.S. If anyone can explain such behavior of Oracle 10g in case of joining with XMLTable() constructed from field it would be nice :)*

Comment: Awesome> XML TABLE WORKS WELL. Thanks a lot